# How to add the static array to the new array list recyclerview using Android java

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have module where I need to list all the data in the recyclerview, I already create this recyclerview on my project however I got error it says that **Change 2nd parameter of method player choices from String to String[]**. So I already change what the error says. right now still got error **incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String**

Here is the array that I want to list on my recyclerview:

```
String[] chicken_choice_status = {"Test", "Test2", "Test", "Test2", "Test", "Test2"};
```

Recyclerview Adapter:

```
 player_choices[] player_choices = new player_choices[] {
            new player_choices("1",chicken_choice_status,3,4,5)
    };

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    PlayerChoiceAdapter adapter = new PlayerChoiceAdapter(player_choices);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the error:

[image: Error]

After updating the class of

```
private String[] bet_ratio;
String[] bet_ratio
public String[] get_bet_ratio() {
    return bet_ratio;
}
public void setBetRation(String[] bet_ratio) {
    this.bet_ratio = bet_ratio;
}
```

I'am now getting error of

[image: Error]

Hope someone help me for this. Thanks

Comment: Could you please post the entire code?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `player_choices` class to determine the type of the `bet_ratio` field. It should be defined as:

> String[]  bet_ratio;

Comment: hi @navylover i tried your recommendation, but there are error. please see the update content.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the `bet_ratio` field should be changed from `String` to `String[]` --

```
String[] bet_ratio;
```

Comment: same with you there are alot of error given after I tried that recommendation

Comment: please see the new post